# Setting up NativeScript on Mac. "The ANDROID_HOME environment variable is not set or it points to a non-existent directory

Tags: android, nativescript

I'm trying to get started with NativeScript, but when I try to run `tns run android`, it gives me:

```
$ tns run android
The ANDROID_HOME environment variable is not set or it points to a non-existent directory. You will not be able to perform any build-related operations for Android.
```

I have already setup ANDROID_HOME in my ~/.bash_profile

```
$ echo $ANDROID_HOME
/Users/mb102/Library/Andriod/sdk
```

This path matches what's in Android Studio manager, where I've also downloaded and setup a device:

```
$ tns devices

Connected devices & emulators
Searching for devices...
┌───┬──────────────────────┬──────────┬───────────────────┬──────────┬───────────┐
│ # │ Device Name          │ Platform │ Device Identifier │ Type     │ Status    │
│ 1 │ sdk_google_phone_x86 │ Android  │ emulator-5554     │ Emulator │ Connected │
└───┴──────────────────────┴──────────┴───────────────────┴──────────┴───────────┘
```

Is there anything more I ought to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The typo in your path?

```
$ echo $ANDROID_HOME
/Users/mb102/Library/Andriod/sdk
```

Should be:

```
$ echo $ANDROID_HOME
/Users/mb102/Library/Android/sdk
```

Actually, shouldnt it be:

```
$ export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/mb102/Library/Android/sdk
```